# Why is using React Context better than just passing around a props object?

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I've been reading about the advantages of using Context in React and I am unconvinced. I'm wondering if there's something I've missed.

> Context provides a way to pass data through the component tree without having to pass props down manually at every level.

What's the hassle in creating a props object in the main component and just passing it around among the underlings? Something like:

```
// do this once at top level (I'm assuming [foo, foo_set] and [bar, bar_set] are state variables):
const props = {foo, foo_set, bar, bar_set, thisAndThat, theOther, whatever, etcAndEtc}

// including one component
<MyComponent1 {...props } />

// including another
<MyComponent2 {...props } />
```

(Maybe better to use another name than props for this object, as the components can have other properties. Anyway.)

Then in MyComponent1 you can access all the props you want, or not access them. Either:

```
...
const MyComponent1 = (props) => {
...
// here we can use any props we need, props.bar, props.bar_set, props.theOther for example
const localVar = props.bar * 2;
props.bar_set(localVar);
// this changes the value of bar throughout the app
...
}
```

the advantage of the above, as I see it, is that you can pass around the props object to other sub-sub-components and not worry about whether you have anything missing.
Or:

```
...
const MyComponent1 = ({bar, bar_set, theOther }) => {
...
// here we can use bar, bar_set, theOther in the same example
const localVar = bar * 2;
bar_set(localVar);
...
}
```

The advantage of this option being that the syntax is shorter.

So my point is why not just use the standard JavaScript syntax? Why introduce new concepts when there are plenty to assimilate to do all sorts of other things?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Consider a fairly common case for most applications: You have authentication information (eg, the current user), a routing library (eg, react-router), and a theme object (what colors to use). These are needed in components scattered throughout the app.

You want to render a button somewhere down at the tip of the component tree. It's going to show the user's avatar, so it needs the authentication data. It's going to navigate when clicked, so it needs the navigate function from the routing library. And it needs to style itself according to the theme.

This certainly *can* be done through props, but in order for the button to get the props, every component in the chain above it must get and forward those props too. This could be many components deep, like page component -> section component -> table -> row -> widget -> button, and most of them don't need that information for themselves, so they're just taking the props in order to forward it along.

And you can easily imagine cases where there are more than 3 pieces of data that are needed across the app.

> What's the hassle

Most people find this "prop drilling" to be a hassle, but let's assume you don't. You still have the problem that it has bad performance. If every component must receive the full set of "global" values that the app might need, then any time anything changes, the entire app must rerender. Optimizations like react.memo become effectively useless. You will get much better performance if you only pass the props you need.

Comment: "any time anything changes, the entire app must rerender" : that's the first argument I've heard that makes any sense... However I would be surprised that React would not be smart enough to see what is used and what isn't in which components.

Comment: `However I'm wondering whether React isn't smart enough to see what is used and what isn't in which components.` React makes no attempt to determine which variables are used and which are not. The main tool for skipping renders is React.memo, but the way this works is to compare the previous props with the next props. If you're passing everything as props, and those values are changing, then React.memo has little to no effect.

Answer (score 0):

Easier to edit code (You don't have to delete for example unused variable)
Better redability (You dont see unnescesary variables, and You see which component is using variables)
Lesser  performance waste (preventing from consuming unnescesarry variables)

Suppose You got 10 descendants in - You would have to pass one variable through 10 of components.
What if some could have the same variable name ? You would have to edit Your passed variable for a while, then edit back later.

Comment: "Better redability (You dont see unnescesary variables)" : you don't see any unnecessary variables either, in the sub-components I gave as examples.

Comment: "Lesser performance waste (preventing from consuming unnescesarry variables)" : I can't imagine that React would not pick the low-lying performance enhancing fruit of checking which variables are used or not...

Comment: But You pass al props  -  if You would care for performance and readability You wouldn't do that.
Hence Context change couses  rerenders descendant components, while changing a value - not.
If You would learn React as class-based (instead of functional ) You it would be probably easier to understand on first look. 
On the begginning i also didn't see a reason of Context.
Better not to pass all possible variables :)

Comment: So React still have to check Your unnescerary props for use, hence, if You pass an object, then object is examined, as it's one argument.
So if You want React to examine every field individually, You have to pass it as individual data. 
So passing props means Your variable passing through out a component  will be kept as long as props are used in this component (read till the end of parent life, read all the time).
Do You count on React to do heuristic opimization ?

Answer (score 0):

To sum up:

- Using Context more efficient than stuffing everything into a single object variable, because it avoids re-rendering the whole app when anything changes.
- People think passing a single variable around is more hassle than introducing specific syntax.
- Context also allows you to have different values for the same variable in different parts of the app. This is shown here (the best explanation IMHO) : https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/passing-data-deeply-with-context
- The above article also specifies that sometimes passing props is the best solution. It gives a list of use cases for context, and the advantages provided in each case.